# Adding cssErrorClass to a div

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using twitter bootstrap for a Spring webapp.

I just added validation and I want to add an error class to the `div.controlGroup` if validation fails.

Part of view:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <form:label cssClass="control-label" path="subject" cssErrorClass="inputError">Subject</form:label>
    <div class="controls">
        <form:input path="subject"/>
        <span class="help-block"><form:errors path="subject" /></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Part of controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addTask(@ModelAttribute("task") Task task, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "tasks";
    }
    taskRepository.save(task);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to add an error class to the div using `<spring:bind>`

```
<spring:bind path="task.dueDate">
<div class="control-group${(not empty status.errorMessage) ? ' error':''}">
</spring:bind>
    <form:label cssClass="control-label" path="dueDate" cssErrorClass="inputError">Due date</form:label>
    <div class="controls">
        <form:input path="dueDate"/>
        <span class="help-block"><form:errors path="dueDate" /></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
<div class="control-group ${requestScope['org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.task'].
        hasFieldErrors('dueDate') ? 'error' : ''}">
```

before, but, apparently, the use of `<spring:bind>` - it's a better way